# The discussion of subgroups $H \subset \mathbb{Z^2}$

Tags: group-theory, matrix-rank, normal-subgroups

I am not sure if the answers of the following question are correct, so if anyone could verify it for me, that would be grateful.

If I take  $H:= \mathbb{Z} \times (2,2) + \mathbb{Z} \times(4,12)$, then I have to compute the following:

- Compute the order of $(1,0) + H$ in $\mathbb{Z^2}/H$, I found that the order is 16 but I am not sure.
- Calculate the rank and the elementary divisors of $\mathbb{Z^2}/H$ , I found that the elementary divisors are 2 and 8. The rank is 2.

For the next question I need help to solve it.

If we let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and take $H:= \mathbb{Z} \times (a,b) + \mathbb{Z} \times(c,d)$, then I have to show that: $\mathbb{Z^2}/H$ can be generated by a single element $\iff gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$.

Comment: The symbol $\ast$ has a specific meaning in group theory; *viz.*, the free product. To type the symbol $\times$ instead for the direct product, use `$\times$`.

Comment: Also, note that $\in$ and $\subseteq$ are distinct.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out exactly what you mean by ${\mathbb Z} \times (2,2)$ as a subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}^2$. I guess you mean the subgroup generated by $(2,2)$, but this is not standard notation. The problem is that the $\times$ symbol suggests a direct product of groups. In the second question, I guess you mean rank and elementary divisors of ${\mathbb Z}^2/H$, but it would help to say so!

Comment: For the first question, note that $(8,0) = (12,12) - (4,12)$ so the order of $(1,0)+H$ is at most $8$.